# Using Wikipedia definitions in research paper

Tags: paper-submission, research-undergraduate

I'm writing a research paper in finance. I'm taking help of Wikipedia  definitions for the introduction part. Do I have to mention it in the Appendix part?

Comment: By "appendix" I think you mean "bibliography" or "references"?

Comment: By "Wikipedia definitions" do you mean wiktionary? Or do you mean definitions given in articles in Wikipedia? It's important as Wiktionary is a secondary source while Wikipedia is a tertiary source.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend that you do not use Wikipedia definitions---they're good as a starting point for informing yourself, but aren't generally considered reliable enough to be citable literature.

Instead, follow the references provided on the Wikipedia page to back up those definitions, and you should be able to find a more primary-source document that is appropriate to take definitions from and to formally cite.